# Strange Behavior : Drupal 8 Views with Contextual Filter and Path Alias Together

Tags: 8, views, path-aliases

I am testing out a views page on core 8.0.5.  The path is set at job/% and the contextual filter is Content: Node ID.  This page view only displays a few fields for testing purpose.  The preview works perfectly whenever I input a node number, e.g. 165, at the "Preview with contextual filters:" prompt.  The preview path shows job/165.  Strange behaviour happens as follows:

1. No path alias used:  everything works accordingly.  I click the preview path (job/165) and it shows up the page mysite.com/job/165 with the few selected fields.  I change the 165 to another number at the url, e.g. 168, and it works.  This is perfect.
2. Path alias used:  the alias pattern is job/[node:nid].  The preview also works fine.  However, when I click the preview path job/165, it brings me to the same page at mysite.com/job/165, but this time it shows the whole content instead of the few selected fields of the view page.  Obviously it is displaying the node content instead of my view page.  If I change the node number at the url, e.g. 168, it still shows the whole node content exactly like mysite.com/node/168.

I've been struggling with this for the whole week.  Did I do something wrong?